# OTB TrainImageClassifiers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, otb-applications

I have installed the OTB 5.10.1 version and when i want to use train images classifier for the random forest it doesn't create any output model file. and the library give me this error message:

```
ERROR: Waiting for at least one parameter...
This is the TrainImagesClassifier application, version 5.10.1
Train a classifier from multiple pairs of images and training vector data.

Complete documentation: http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/Applications/TrainImagesClassifier.html

Parameters:
-progress Report progress
MISSING -io.il Input Image List (mandatory)
MISSING -io.vd Input Vector Data List (mandatory)
-io.valid Validation Vector Data List (optional, off by default)
-io.imstat Input XML image statistics file (optional, off by default)
-io.confmatout Output confusion matrix (optional, off by default)
MISSING -io.out Output model (mandatory)
-elev.dem DEM directory (optional, off by default)
-elev.geoid Geoid File (optional, off by default)
-elev.default Default elevation (mandatory, default value is 0)
-sample.mt Maximum training sample size per class (mandatory, default value is 1000)
-sample.mv Maximum validation sample size per class (mandatory, default value is 1000)
-sample.bm Bound sample number by minimum (mandatory, default value is 1)
-sample.vtr Training and validation sample ratio (mandatory, default value is 0.5)
-sample.vfn Field Name (mandatory, default value is )
-classifier Classifier to use for the training [libsvm] (mandatory, default value is libsvm)
-classifier.libsvm.k SVM Kernel Type [linear/rbf/poly/sigmoid] (mandatory, default value is linear)
-classifier.libsvm.m SVM Model Type [csvc/nusvc/oneclass] (mandatory, default value is csvc)
-classifier.libsvm.c Cost parameter C (mandatory, default value is 1)
-classifier.libsvm.opt Parameters optimization (optional, off by default)
-classifier.libsvm.prob Probability estimation (optional, off by default)
-rand set user defined seed (optional, off by default)
-ram Available RAM (Mb) (optional, off by default, default value is 128)
-cleanup Temporary files cleaning (optional, on by default)
-inxml Load otb application from xml file (optional, off by default)
```

It give me only the libsvm classification.

Comment: Could you please show how you start the classification? You seem to miss some mandatory parameters in your function call.